# Bizagi create dynamic combobox

Tags: dynamic, combobox, business-process-management, bizagi

Guys!
I'm working on a project with Bizagi Suite - Version 11.1. I'm new to it and I will really appreciate your help, because I'm having a hard time creating a dynamic combobox control. 
So my case is the following:
Data Model: 3 master tables: Program, Order and Order-Program (m-m relationship). In table Program users fill out year, positions and amounts for each position. In table Order, they fill out info about the order and they have to specify from which program they want to take the money out for the order. The Program itself has a lot of records with different positions and amount. And I want when the users fill out the order to select the year, the position and the amount they want to take out of the program. So I need to have a dynamic combobox for the field 'position'  which loads when user select year.

In other words I need to load combobox with filtered records of master table.
Do you have any ideas how I can do that?

Thank you in advance!

Best regards, 
A.Mincheva

Answer (score 1):

You must define your combobox with the full content of the master table.
Then ,you can define a Filter expression to dynamically filter the combobox content.
In the filter expression, you need to retreive the value of selected Year with XPath and use this value to filter the records.

In the form designer, you go to "Actions & Validations" to define the following action :

When "Year" changes *<=The display name of the input field*
Then Refresh "Program" *<=The display name of your dynamic combobox*

Comment: Thank you, Arnaud! I think it will be working like that with the filters.